# Boilerplate for all proceeds from a project going to a specific charity?

Tags: contract-law, digital-contract

I need an as-simple-as-possible document that basically states that nobody involved is going to earn any money from the proceeds of sales from the projects, but that all the proceeds are going to go directly to (a charitable organization to be named).

To be a little more specific, I am going to put together a "value-added" book - from the public domain (a Mark Twain work) with drawings provided by middle-school students. They and I agree to send ALL the proceeds to a charitable org.

Is there a "boilerplate" document for this that is available online somewhere - one that simply states that those signing it are releasing any financial interest in the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "as-simple-as-possible document" is easily created by writing down exactly what you intend to do.

If you are going to give all the money to charity, say that. If you are going to use the money to pay expenses like printing and distribution costs and give what's left over to charity, say that. Then do what you say and keep records to prove you did it.

One other thing, charitable donations are usually tax deductible. Who is going to get the benefit of that tax deduction?

Comment: Thanks; I hadn't thought of the last point. We (the contributors to the project) will need to discuss that.